# jQuery Drag and Drop with sortable UI not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently trying to create a drag and drop, with sortable list items... But when I'm moving the draggable item towards the placeholder, it just returns to it's place. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I found this method [here](https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/draggable/sortable.html), but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="draggable">

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
        <h1>1</h1>
        <p>Description 1</p>
    </li>

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
        <h1>2</h1>
        <p>Description 2</p>
    </li>

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
        <h1>3</h1>
        <p>Description 3</p>
    </li>

</ul>

<div style="height: 100px; clear: both;"></div>

<ul id="dropzone" class="items">

    <li class="placeholder"></li>

</ul>
```

And this is the jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    $("#draggable li.to-drag").draggable({

        connectWith: "#dropzone",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        droppable: "drop"

    });

    $("#dropzone").droppable({

        drop: function( event, ui) {

            $(this).addClass("correct");

        }

    });

    $("ul, li").disableSelection();

});
```

Thanks for the help! :)

**EDIT**

This is the working jQuery:

```
$(function() {

$("#dropzone").sortable({

    revert: true,
    opacity: 0.5

});

$("#draggable li").draggable({

    connectToSortable: ".items",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: true,
    opacity: 0.5

});

$("li.placeholder").droppable({
    revert: false,

    drop: function (event, ui) {

        var dragging = ui.draggable.clone();

        $(this).append(dragging);

    }

});

$("ul, li").disableSelection();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got at least three major problems:

- `Draggable` doesn't have `connectWith`, it has `connectToSortable`.
  So you should change this. See doc:
  http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/
- To use `connectToSortable`, you need a `sortable`, not at
  `droppable`.
- You'll need to change `drop` event for a sortable event, `receive`
  maybe or `update`, depending on what you need.
  http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

It could look like this:

```
$(function() {

    $("#draggable li.to-drag").draggable({

        connectToSortable: "#dropzone",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
        droppable: "drop"

    });

    $("#dropzone").sortable({

        receive: function( event, ui) {

            $(this).addClass("correct");

        }

    });

    $("ul, li").disableSelection();

});
```

Comment: Thanks.. Here you have provided so clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the changes I have made

```
    $(function() {

    $("#draggable li.to-drag").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
      helper: "clone",
        revert:"invalid"
    });

    $("#dropzone1").droppable({

        drop:function( event, ui) {
alert(ui.draggable.text())
$("#dropzone").text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );


        }

    });

    $("ul, li").disableSelection();

});
```

The additional div ensures you are dragging on to the right panel

```
    <ul id="draggable">

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
        <h1>1</h1>
        <p>Description 1</p>
    </li>

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
        <h1>2</h1>
        <p>Description 2</p>
    </li>

    <li class="to-drag" class="items">
        <h1>3</h1>
        <p>Description 3</p>
    </li>

</ul>

<div style="height: 100px; clear: both;"></div>
<div id="dropzone1" style="border:solid 1px">
    <ul id="dropzone" class="items" >

    <li class="placeholder"></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Requires some tweaking to get some additional functionality but you should be able to do this

you will need additional code to do the sorting

Check out this link [here](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart)
Cheers
Truez